# how can I re-run a process that I killed

Tags: linux

I've killed a process called `636 wpa_supplicant`. How can I run it again.

I've googled a lot all the results are about how to kill a process.
I know that if I restarted my machine it will be running again, however I don't want to restart it.

Comment: Maybe just execute `wpa_supplicant` ?

Comment: In the search, did you include stuff about you killing it?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor yes I did

Comment: @AbdulrahmanAbdullah what will explain "... all the results are about how to kill a process." -- try not mentioning killing it. As this is not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Run something like this from the terminal:

```
/usr/sbin/wpa_supplicant -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf &
```

Comment: Probably as root?